# interpolate.interp1d linear plot doesn't agree with new inputs to the function

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

I have used scipy.interpolate.interp1d to have a linear interpolation between two arrays with float values. Then, I plotted the interpolation function with matplotlib. However, I noticed that some new values (that weren't originally included in the arrays representing x and y data) yield different results when plugged into the interpolation function, than what the plot suggests.

I am essentially trying to find the intersection points between a few lines that are parallel to the x-axis and the interpolation function's linear curve. By research online, I saw that many people use scipy's interpolate.interp1d for this purpose.

Here is the code:

```py
from scipy import interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
size = [12, 9, 6.5, 4.8, 2, 0.85, 0.45, 0.15, 0.07]
poW = [100, 99, 98, 97, 94, 80, 50, 6, 1]

# Approximate function f: size = f(poW)
f = interpolate.interp1d(poW, size, kind="linear") 

# Here I create the plot
plt.axes(xscale='log') # scale x-axis
plt.plot(size, poW, "bs", # add data points with blue squares
         f(poW), poW, "b") # add a blue trendline

# Draw D_10 as an additional point
plt.plot(f(10), 10, "rx", markersize=15)

# Draw D_30 as an additional point
plt.plot(f(30), 30, "rx", markersize=15)

# Draw D_60 as an additional point
plt.plot(f(60), 60, "rx", markersize=15)

plt.show()
```

The additional points I plot in the last 3 lines before `plt.show()`, don't correspond to the same positions indicated by the plot of the interpolation function itself. This is pretty interesting for me, and I can't seem to locate the problem here. I am pretty new to matplotlib and scipy, so I am sure I must be missing something. Any help or pointing in the right direction will be appreciated!

Comment: Things look fine if you comment out `plt.axes(xscale='log')`. The issue seems to me that you are fitting on a linear scale but using a log scale for axis

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Uncommenting the line does seem to make things better, but I still notice a slight difference. Also, why would that be an issue? To my knowledge, the log scale for the x-axis shouldn't cause any differences; it is just another way to represent the same data.

Comment: The slight difference on linear scale is only a graphical issue of marker stamping. You may zoom into to plot to see that there is no difference in data. In contrast to that, on a log scale the difference is indeed real. This is because a linear interpolation on a linear scale is not linear on a logarithmic scale.